# Filtering data in a datagridview using date

Tags: c#, datagridview

I'm trying to filter my data in a datagridview by 2 date columns - startDate and endDate.

i want to check if the end date expired for arow in the the but the value of acheck box on grid view = "Expired" else put it ="Valid"

but i do not know how to make it true please help me to do this ?!

here is my code that i tried :

```
        SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
        SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter();
        sda.SelectCommand.CommandText = "select TASDEED.ID ,ESALNO,DATTSADEED,NAME,EGARMONY,DATBEGIN,DATEND,AKARTYPE  from TASDEED ";
        try
        {
            foreach (DataGridView row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    if (myStatic.CalcExpire(dt.Rows[i]["DATEND"].ToString()))//
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = "Expired";
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[8].Value = "Valid";
                    }

                }
            }
            BindingSource bsource = new BindingSource();
            bsource.DataSource = dt;
            dataGridView1.DataSource = bsource;
            sda.Update(dt);
           sda.Fill(dt);
        }
        catch(Exception ex) 
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

And That is my CalaExpire function :

```
    public static bool CalcExpire(string datee)
    {
        try
        {
            string[] Arr = datee.Split('/');
            long Day1 = Convert.ToInt64(Arr[2]);
            long Month1 = Convert.ToInt64(Arr[1]);
            long Year1 = Convert.ToInt64(Arr[0]);

            System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar UmDate = new System.Globalization.UmAlQuraCalendar();
            long Day = Convert.ToInt64(UmDate.GetDayOfMonth(DateTime.Now));
            long Month = Convert.ToInt64(UmDate.GetMonth(DateTime.Now));
            long Year = Convert.ToInt64(UmDate.GetYear(DateTime.Now));

            if (Year > Year1)
                return true;
            else if (Year == Year1 && Month > Month1)
                return true;
            else if (Year == Year1 && Month == Month1 && Day >= Day1)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
        catch { return false; }
    }
```

Comment: Could you please show your myStatic.CalcExpire method ?

Comment: You're looping through rows before you set datasource. That will always fail :( You should directly set value in DataTable instead of `DataGridView`

Comment: Sriram Sakthivel ,could you write code please